# selecting a subset of a matrix

Tags: r

I am new to R and feel a bit stupid asking this question.

Below is my code. Say if my data is a matrix of 100 rows and 3 columns. I want to split my data into train and test data using the first 80 rows as my training data & the last 20 as my testing data.

However running the code below, I can see x_test & y_test both have 100 rows, why?

```
data_dim <- dim(data_input)
split_row <- round(data_dim[1] * 0.8)

x_train <- data_input[1:split_row, 1 : data_dim[2]-1]
y_train <- data_input[1:split_row, data_dim[2]]
x_test <- data_input[split_row + 1 : data_dim[1], 1 : data_dim[2]-1]
y_test <- data_input[split_row + 1 : data_dim[1], data_dim[2]]
```

Comment: do you need to do this manually? also please provide a reprex, just plugging in mtcars should be enough

Comment: anyway would be good :-)

Comment: @mHelpMe it's because you are selecting the same rows for both `x_test` and `y_test`. You have put `data_input[split_row + 1 : data_dim[1], ` as the start of both `x_test` and `y_test`. The part before the comma tells you the rows, the part after the comma is the columns. You are choosing the same rows but different columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest fix is to add some parens to make it clear what rows you want

```r
set.seed(2020)
data_input <- matrix(runif(300), nrow = 100, ncol = 3)
data_dim <- dim(data_input)
split_row <- round(data_dim[1] * 0.8)

x_train <- data_input[1:split_row, 1 : data_dim[2]-1]
y_train <- data_input[1:split_row, data_dim[2]]
x_test <- data_input[(split_row + 1) : data_dim[1], 1 : data_dim[2]-1]
y_test <- data_input[(split_row + 1) : data_dim[1], data_dim[2]]
```

`caret::createDataPartition` is a nice tool for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking into tidymodels

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)

mtcars_split <- mtcars %>% initial_split(prop = .8)
train <- mtcars_split %>% training()
test <- mtcars_split %>% testing()

# Should not be needed on tidymodels

y_train <- train %>% select(mpg)
x_train <- train %>% select(-mpg)

y_test <- test %>% select(mpg)
x_test <- test %>% select(-mpg)
```